# Eclipse - Java Issue finding the controller

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, model-view-controller

I am learning JSP through a French JSP book full of tutorials. I'm currently learning "MVC & Jsp" basically, with a Catalog of DVD and a Shopping cart. A controller adds dvds to the cart when the user clicks on the add button.
However, it appears that my controller isn't called. I place a System.Out when it is called to check if it works, and there is no text popping on my console...
**Here is my project explorer.**

[image]

**And here are my codes for my catalog and my Controller.**

```
<%@page import="exoLivres.ShoppingCart"%>

<%@ page errorPage="../PagesErreur/Erreurpage.jsp" %>
<jsp:useBean id="cart" scope="session" class="exoLivres.ShoppingCart" />
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Catalogue DVD</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="U:/workspace/myfirstProject/WebContent/MVC/ShoppingCartMVC.jsp">Quantité actuelle : </a> <%=cart.getNumOfItems() %>
    <hr>
        <center><h3>Catalogue DVD</h3></center>
        <table border="1">
                <tr><th>Description</th><th>Prix</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <form action="ShopController" method="post">
<!--no error, but nothing happening-->
                <td>Frozen</td>
                <td>$19.95</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Ajouter"></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="desc" value="Frozen">
                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="19.95">
                <input type="hidden" name="command" value="add">
            </form>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form action="ShopController" method="post">
<!--no error, but nothing happening-->
                <td>XMen Origins</td>
                <td>$19.95</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Ajouter"></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="desc" value="XMen">
                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="19.95">
                <input type="hidden" name="command" value="add">
        </form>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form action="ShopController" method="post">
                <td>Avengers</td>
                <td>$17.95</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Ajouter"></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="desc" value="Avengers">
                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="17.95">
                <input type="hidden" name="command" value="add">
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**and my controller**

```
package exoLivres;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import exoLivres.ShoppingCart;


public class ShopController extends HttpServlet {

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
        super.init(config);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        System.out.println("Contrôleur démarré");
        String command= request.getParameter("command");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart)session.getAttribute("cart");

        if(command.equals("add")){
            String id = request.getParameter("id");
            if (id!=null){
                System.out.println(id);
                String desc = request.getParameter("desc");
                Float price = new Float(request.getParameter("price"));
                cart.addItem(id, desc, price.floatValue(), 1);
                System.out.println(id + desc + price);
            }
        }
        response.sendRedirect("U:/workspace/myfirstProject/WebContent/MVC/Catalogue.jsp");
    }
    public String getServletInfo(){
        return "ShopController Information";
    }

}
```

I guess the problem is from my references to my Controller but I can't think of the correct reference. Any help welcome =)

EDIT
Okay so here is my web.xmm [I also did the modifications suggered on my code above, and removed every "e" I wrote at the end of method (and not methode)]
        
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyfirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myfirstProject.MyfirstServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyfirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/first</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Books</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myfirstProject.BookServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Books</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/books</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ShopController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>exoLivres.ShopController</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ShopController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ShopController</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

Comment: just a small sidenote : JSP is woefully outdated and ... pretty bad. Consider JSF or something similar, probably even Vaadin - that'll prevent _a lot_ of headaches, trust me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working in a society for a work placement and I will have to use JSP so I don't have much option =)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way you set action to the form. 
action="U:/workspace/myfirstProjet/src/ShopController"
I think it should be action="Name_Of_CLass" not path to the class.

Comment: I tried it [ <form action="exoLivres.ShopController" methode="post"> ] but JBoss tells me the resource is not available (the kind of error you get when the path is wrong) and in the book, their code is : <form action="C:/jakarta-tomat/purejsp/ShopController"> ... However I'm using JBoss and I don't know what path I should write (since everything I tried resulted in an error)

Answer (score 0):

Also notice that the sendRedirect receives a url location not the path to the jsp in your project. (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29)

So in your servlet (controller) and your jsp, rename this "U:/workspace/myfirstProjet/build/classes/exoLivres/ShopController" to something like this: "/myfirstProjet/".

and where you have "U:/workspace/myfirstProject/WebContent/MVC/Catalogue.jsp"
rename to "/myfirstProjet/".

Comment: Okay so I edited like this  
in my Catalog, I tried 3 different ways to call my controller
<form action="exoLivres.ShopController" methode="post">
<form action="/myfirstProject/ShopController" methode="post">
<form action="/myfirstProject/exoLivres.ShopController" methode="post">

But none of them is working. "(/myfirstProject/MVC/exoLivres.ShopController) is not disponible" (translating it from French, might no be the true English Error) 

And in my controller response.sendRedirect("/myfirstProject/Catalogue.jsp"); (although I can't know for now if that works)

Comment: Only your last attempt is valid. And I think it's correct. To find the url of the server, I think the best way is by investigating your web.xml file in the WEB-INF folder. (can you add it to the post pls)

Answer (score 0):

You must have your controller mapping in the web.xml

You have not given path of your ShopController controller in this

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyfirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myfirstProject.MyfirstServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyfirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/first</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Books</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myfirstProject.BookServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Books</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/books</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It should be like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ShopController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>packagename.ShopController</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ShopController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ShopController</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And change the action of your jsp form as below..

```
 <form action="ShopController" method="post">
<!--no error, but nothing happening-->
                <td>XMen Origins</td>
                <td>$19.95</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Ajouter"></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="desc" value="XMen">
                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="19.95">
                <input type="hidden" name="command" value="add">
        </form>
```

To prevent get method not supported change controller like this

```
public class ShopController extends HttpServlet {

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
        super.init(config);
    }


 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

processRequest(request,response)
}

 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

processRequest(request,response)
}


 public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

 System.out.println("Contrôleur démarré");
        String command= request.getParameter("command");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart)session.getAttribute("cart");

        if(command.equals("add")){
            String id = request.getParameter("id");
            if (id!=null){
                System.out.println(id);
                String desc = request.getParameter("desc");
                Float price = new Float(request.getParameter("price"));
                cart.addItem(id, desc, price.floatValue(), 1);
                System.out.println(id + desc + price);
            }
        }
        response.sendRedirect("U:/workspace/myfirstProject/WebContent/MVC/Catalogue.jsp");

}

}
```

Comment: Indeed, I had forgotten that. Mistake corrected. However, while I was hopping that would be the problem... Looks like it wasn't the only one. When running my Catalog (I saved every file, restarted JBoss) it still tells me that it can't find my Controller (I edited my code up there with my current code). Eclipse is looking for my controller here "http://localhost:8080/myfirstProject/MVC/ShopController" which is absolutely not where it should look for.

Comment: "localhost:8080/myfirstProject/MVC/ShopController  you dont need MVC in the url..Give this a try localhost:8080/myfirstProject/ShopController

Comment: That (somehow) works (somehow because I now have an error about the GET method not supported... When my form is supposed to work with POST). However, how come Eclipse looks in that folder (which is the folder for my JSP files but not my JAVA files), and how can I prevent that ?